# tikzpicture printed in the wrong position

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning, printing

I want to have my picture printed in the right corner of an A4 paper. To place it there I use tikzpicture. But when I print it out it is not in the same position as I can see it in the PDF. I thought it might because I do not define the paper size. But after using the `geometry` package it is still in the wrong position. Here is the example code with the tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article} % Starts an article
\usepackage{amsmath} % Imports amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\title{\LaTeX} % Title

\begin{document} % Begins a document
  \maketitle
  \LaTeX{} is a document preparation system for
  the \TeX{} typesetting program. It offers
  programmable desktop publishing features and
  extensive facilities for automating most
  aspects of typesetting and desktop publishing,
  including numbering and  cross-referencing,
  tables and figures, page layout,
  bibliographies, and much more. \LaTeX{} was
  originally written in 1984 by Leslie Lamport
  and has become the  dominant method for using
  \TeX; few people write in plain \TeX{} anymore.
  The current version is \LaTeXe.

  % This is a comment, not shown in final output.
  % The following shows typesetting  power of LaTeX:
  \begin{align}
    E_0 &= mc^2 \\
    E &= \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
  \end{align} 
  

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [anchor=south east,yshift=0pt,xshift=0]%
        at (current page.south east)
        {\includegraphics[height=13mm]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}
```

The first picture is how I see it on the screen in the PDF and it does not matter whether I use `geometry` or not . On the second picture on the left is the print out wit `geometry` and the second is without `geometry`. I tried it on two different printers, so I assume it has nothing to do with the printers, but idk.

[image: PDF position] [image: printout]

Comment: When I compile it the pdf looks normal (picture in lower right corner) and so does the print out. So I think there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: So does it look like in the PDF file? It would mean it depends on the printer, like paper is placed and pulled etc.

Comment: Yes my pdf and print out look the same.

Comment: Try to print from different pdf viewers, and check the scaling options of the viewer. Everything should be set to something amounting to "don't apply any corrections".

Comment: @gernot, I used `testflow_ctl_A4.pdf` to test this. So it seems that my printer is stopping printing at 19mm on long edges and 21mm on the short edges. Keeping this in mind, how should I design my PDFs?  Since default printing is probably scaling down to 96%, probably just let the picture be where I initially put it?

Comment: Printers usually don't have such large borders where they cannot print. Usually the border is just a few millimeters. Try to print a test page. Finally, you have to decide whether you want to have your document printed in a fixed size, or whether it is ok that the viewer/print driver scales the page to fit the printing area. In the first case, you have to make sure that TeX puts everything in the correct place, and disable all scaling options when printing. I'm afraid I can't give any advice, since it all depends on your specific printing environment.

Comment: Just for clarification and in a case when someone as clueless as I am is reading this. I mentioned the number from the scale used in the test PDF above: `testflow_ctl_A4.pdf`. The border is really just a few millimeters 5 and 4 respectively.

Comment: @Namal If you want the image to be *really* in the lower right corner, use `inner sep=0` as in `\node[inner sep=0, anchor=south east] ...` (your `yshift=0pt,xshift=0` is useless here, so I removed it).